# Use String.Split to split by character in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string named String1. How can I use String.Split to split it by letters into letters[].

As an example, say `String1 = "Hello World"`. How can I split it so that `letters[0] = H`, `letters[1] = e`, `letters[2] = l`, and so on.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: And also note you can already use e.g. String1[0], String1[1] on your default string to get its letters, without manual splitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) class in .NET has an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netframework-4.8), which allows you to access the `char` value at specific position in a string. So, you can do something like that

```cs
var String1 = "Hello World";
var letter = String1[0]; //equals `H`
letter = String1[1]; //equals `e`
```

Another option is to use [`ToCharArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_ToCharArray) method, it copies the characters from a `string` instance to a character array

```cs
var String1 = "Hello World";
var array = String1.ToCharArray();
```

But there is no need to copy the string to a char array (unless you have a good reason for that), indexer is just enough